# Applying for 2 different jobs in same company through 2 headhunters

Tags: interviewing, recruitment

I applied 'A'position at "K" company last week, The position is not perfectly matching my experience but I applied it with head hunter "A"
(I haven't heard back from them about the next step yet.)

Today, a head hunter 'B', contacted to me regarding the  position 'B' at the same company "K" that I am more interested in. I really want to apply this position,
so would it be a problem to apply 2 different positions at the same company 
through different headhunter?

Comment: I am afraid it probably would be a problem as the head hunter typically enters a contract with the company where if they hire you for any position then they get a fee.   You could be honest with B and hear what they have to say.

Comment: @Paparazzi I hadn't thought of that, is that usual practice?

Answer (score 1):

This happens more commonly than you think.

if the roles are very similar (or the same), often companies will decline the referral from the second headhunter. Or rather, they should. Headhunters understand what this means.

If the roles are not similar, if it's a different position, then this (probably) doesn't present a problem to the company. It's likely, if they are organised, they'll identify you're applying for multiple positions and  handle it. At the very least, they should do reference checking once, and you should be prescreened once. They may give you an joint interview with stakeholders from both positions, and whatever position you are selected for dictates which headhunter gets the "cut". Or they may decide you should sit through both interviews.

Either way, you've done nothing wrong. On the contrary, you've showed a commitment to getting a job.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem. It's no different then applying at two different companies.

The only possible downside is that someone in HR sees both and realises it's the same person and decides you're desperate for work and tries to negotiate a lesser pay over it. But I can't realistically see that happening.

It's totally normal for people to apply for multiple jobs simultaneously when job hunting.

Comment: Yes, it's totally normal for people to apply to multiple jobs simultaneously, but it's also totally normal for HR to filter out resumes for the flimsiest of reasons. In other words, you should disclose by email to the second recruiter that you already applied to that first company through a first headhunter. If there is a standard protocol for that kind of thing, that headhunter should know what it is.

Comment: Nope, OP runs the risk of having them both getting thrown out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are presented by two different recruiters, they may pass on you because they might end up having to pay both.

Answer (score 0):

If you apply through a second recruiter, then the company has a dilemma:

Which recruiter is entitled to get paid for "introducing" you?  This money is the recruiters' bread-and-butter, and a recruiter with bruised feelings about the situation may decide to sue the employer.  Knowing this, most companies will outright reject a candidate if there's anything looking like a double-submission within a given period of time (usually a year).  That even applies for a different position -- because a recruiter won't necessarily convey the official job title to the candidate.

With more than one recruiter in the mix, there's far too much going on in a situation as described that can result in litigation.  Human resources will pump the brakes.

If you're really interested in the second position, have the first recruiter press for it.  As for the second recruiter, it's really not your problem to fix -- it's a highly competitive field.